# How do I commit existing changes after I set a new remote repository?

Tags: git, github

I'm a git newbie and recently inherited a non-functional project with had access to the local production version of the code. I made changes to the local, checked out branch to get it running again. I couldn't commit those changes because the remote GitHub repository was private, so I created a new repository and tried to check in the code to the new repository hoping to maintain the history of the project. Here's a bit of what I tried:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/newrepo.git
git commit -m "initial commit to new github repo"
git push -u origin --all
git push --prune https://github.com/newrepo.git +refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
git push --mirror https://github.com/newrepo.git
```

None of that worked - I wound up with only the readme in the new repository, perhaps because I didn't have read access to the original? I'm not sure.

I've since gotten access to the original private repository and cloned it to a new, clean repo so that I can maintain the history of the project. I'd like to do a check in with the local copy of the code (with changes) to get everything caught up. What's the best way to do that?

When I do a `git status` it no longer shows the previous list of changed files (because of the commit I assume). Should I do a `git commit -a` then push? I'm just not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding:

- You have a working version of a copy of the original repo on your computer but the remote repo for folder is not so good (let's call it RepoB)
- You now have write access to the original repo (RepoA)

I suggest 3 consider options (among many possible others):

- OptionB. Fix up RepoB and create a pull request to RepoA
- OptionC. Forget RepoB, create RepoC from your local changes, push your changes and create a pull request From RepoC to RepoA
- OptionA. Forget RepoB, migrate the local changes to RepoA.

For your case I suggest C, since it's should be very simple to do and what happened go RepoB is irrelevant.

## Option C

1. `cd path/to/repoA`
2. `git checkout -b theBestBranchNameEver` - create a new branch in **RepoA**.
3. Copy RepoB **without** the .git folder onto RepoA.
4. Now repoA contains the changes you made locally. You can follow usual git flow for committing and pushing changes.
5. `git add --all`
6. `git commit -am "Commit message here"`
7. `git push`

Now RepoA contains a branch with your local changes as a single commit. You can now merge your changes to a common branch (something like `develop` or `master`).

At no point you need any forcing or advanced git commands.

Comment: I think I understand - you're suggesting I:

1. create a new directory
2. check out a new branch in that directory 
3. copy the local files (minus .git) into that directory so it has changes
4. do a git add/commit/push.

Now github has the lastest changes. This seems to be a pretty safe option. Do I have it right?

Comment: Thanks @tymtam, this worked and was easy for me to understand as a newbie. I think force push VonC described would be the "right" way, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

> I wound up with only the readme in the new repository

When  you create your new Repository, make sure to create it *empty*.

But in your case, since it has been created with one commit, force push.

```
git push --force -u origin master
git push --all
```

---

> I'd like to do a check in with the local copy of the code (with changes) to get everything caught up

You can set the worktree folder to your old clone just for importing your changes, using the [`--work-tree` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---work-treeltpathgt):

```
cd /path/to/local/clone
git --work-tree=/path/to/local/copy/with/changes add .
git commit -m "Integrate changes"
```

Comment: I would not recommend `--force` to a beginner. Even for an OK `git` user like me these instructions are confusing.

Comment: @tymtam force push on a brand new remote repository? That will be fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Let me rephrase it so I'm sure I understand. The --force command should push all the local files to the new repository.

Setting the worktree folder essentially tells git that my local/copy/with/changes is the directory that I want to use to commit, then I do a standard commit.

They seem to accomplish the same thing. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: @Perry The force push does not just push the files, but the files *history*, replacing the remote repo history (of *one* commit with a README) with your local history: this is the simpler fix.

Comment: @Perry The difference with the work-tree add approach is that you lose the history of your local repository, and make one giant commit with your local files. Then do a regular push.

Comment: @VonC - thanks for the explanation. The force push was exactly what I was looking for. I actually wound up using tymtam's suggestion because I understood it more intuitively, but knowing how both of these methods work will be useful.

Comment: @Perry I did not understood tymtam's suggestions. I laid out simpler options.